# Android - ImageView with rounded only one corner

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, rounded-corners, material-components-android

I want to create ImageView like this (right side of the image):

[image]

I have it in CardView layout so I have rounded corners of the card but I need to create rounded left bottom corner of the image alone (or with top right).

I tried several options but nothing work correctly.

How can I do this? Do you have some tip?

Comment: Wrap you `imageview` inside `cardView`

Comment: Wrap this `ImageView` inside a `CardView` with left bottom corner rounded or round the corner of `bitmap` programmatically.

Comment: How can I set only one rounded corner in `CardView`?

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: What if you use a `CardView` to wrap the image, but use negative top and right margins so that you don't see those rounded corners?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).
With the version **`1.2.0-alpha03`** there is the new **`ShapeableImageView`**.

Just use in your layout:

```
  <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/..."
      ../>
```

And in your code apply the **`ShapeAppearanceModel`** with:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);
imageView.setShapeAppearanceModel(imageView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
    .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
    .build());
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library and put your ImageView inside the Layout

https://github.com/JcMinarro/RoundKornerLayouts

and can set the radius for specific corners like this

```kotlin
containerLayout.setCornerRadius(2f, CornerType.ALL);
containerLayout.setCornerRadius(2f, CornerType.BOTTOM_LEFT);
```

Other choices

```kotlin
public final enum class CornerType private constructor() : kotlin.Enum<com.jcminarro.roundkornerlayout.CornerType> {
    ALL,

    TOP_LEFT,

    TOP_RIGHT,

    BOTTOM_RIGHT,

    BOTTOM_LEFT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/person" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and in your activity :

```
 ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        Bitmap bitImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.person);
        image.setImageBitmap(createRoundedRectBitmap(bitImg, 0, 20, 0, 20));
    }


    private static Bitmap createRoundedRectBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, float topLeftCorner, float topRightCorner, float bottomRightCorner,
                                                  float bottomLeftCorner) {

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);


        final int color = Color.WHITE;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        Path path = new Path();
        float[] radii = new float[]{
                topLeftCorner, bottomLeftCorner,
                topRightCorner, topRightCorner,
                bottomRightCorner, bottomRightCorner,
                bottomLeftCorner, bottomLeftCorner
        };

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        path.addRoundRect(rectF, radii, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simple just make drawable resource file **text_logo_fix.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

and set this drawable file in ImageView property  `android:background`

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/herenamedrawableresourcefile"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/text_logo_fix" />
```

or you can look like this way

```
<LinearLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/herenamedrawableresourcefile">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/text_logo_fix" />
        </LinearLayout>
```